What does relative speed really mean when ejecting something?
This question is motivated by the following very simple question from Chapter 3 of Taylor's Classical Mechanics:

Consider a gun of mass $M$ (when unloaded) that fires a shell of mass m with muzzle speed $v$. (That is, the shell’s speed relative to the gun is $v$.) Assuming that the gun is completely free to recoil (no external forces on gun or shell), use conservation of momentum to show that the shell’s speed relative to the ground is $v/(1+ m/M)$.

My solution is simple, though I have been very long-winded and deliberate in order to point out my question:

Choosing the ground as our reference frame and considering motion along the x-axis only in this 1D problem (the motion of each particle in the system after the gun firing is of the form $\mathbf{r}_i = x_i\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ with corresponding velocities $\mathbf v_i = v_i \mathbf{\hat{x}}$) we have
$$P = 0 = mv_s + Mv_g.$$
Now we will use primed quantities in the gun's reference frame, which has its axes aligned with the ground frame so that reference frame translation is very simple. Then, since the shell's position in the ground frame can be written as $\mathbf r_s = \mathbf r_g + \mathbf r_s'$ we get, on differentiating this, that $\mathbf v_s = \mathbf v_g + \mathbf v_s'$. In the $\mathbf{\hat{x}}$ direction, this means that $v_s = v_g + v$, where we have in particular used that $\mathbf v_s'$ is the velocity of the shell relative to the gun after the two have separated. Putting this into the first equation so as to eliminate $v_g$ and simplifying we see that
$$0 = mv_s + M(v_s - v) \implies v_s = \frac{M}{M + m}v = \frac{v}{1+m/M}.$$

As you can see, I had to define the "shell's speed relative to the gun", $v$, as the speed relative to the gun after the firing was complete, i.e. after the interaction had taken place. I suppose this is the only natural choice and so I'm struggling to exactly describe my confusion, but in short I am wondering if relative velocity in an ejection-type scenario is a sort of a posteriori thing: it's something we back out by analyzing the velocities of both bodies after their interaction is complete? Or is there a way to "look internally" to the interaction in order to determine this relative velocity.
For example, in the derivation of the rocket equation one also tends to speak of the relative velocity of the fuel (to the rocket), and again what one means is the velocity relative to the rocket once the ejection is complete.

You can really define any frame you please.  However, in this particular case, the only information you are given is information after the ejection, so it's natural that you only considered the reference frame after ejection.  In other problems, where you are given different information, you may be able to speak to the state before ejection.
I think the source of complexity here is that your gun firing is a violent action, and it is very common not to fully describe a violent action, but merely its aftermath.  If you had a more controlled ejection, such as a spring or hydraulic piston pushing it, you could answer the questions differently (I believe this is the kind of different you are mentioning when you say "look internally")
